# How do I put someone else as owner on a github repository?

Tags: github, repository, fork, owner

I was trying to fork a github repository. I was expecting to put another owner since I am not going to be it , but I am in charge of creating the repository. However, when forking and electing the owner, it doesn't appear in my list. What can I do? I attached an image and, as you can see, I'm the unique option to be the owner[loner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utwm9.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the ownership of original repository on GitHub.

If you fork a repository on GitHub,that repository is created under your account, and now you have become the owner of this forked repository only, and not the original repository, so you can't change the ownership of the original repository. However if you want to change owner of the forked repository then here are two ways you can do it.

1. You can transfer ownership of the repository to another GitHub user or organization. To do this, go to the forked repository's page, click on the "Settings" tab, and then click on "Transfer ownership" in the left sidebar. Follow the instructions to transfer the ownership.
2. To give ownership of repository to someone else from the beginning, you can create a new repository instead of forking. Go to your GitHub account, click on the "+" sign at the top-right corner, and choose "New repository." Then, fill in the necessary details and set the owner as the desired GitHub user or organization.

Comment: That last one option is what I'm trying to do. But look at the image. I cannot select another owner and that's the problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utwm9.png